# products with lots of attributes combinations in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site using woocommerce, I have imported products from an old oscommerce site, some of the products have several attributes, woocommerce threats those attributes as combinations, the problem is that each product come imported with thousands of combinations and my site crashes.

One example (Not real site):

I have one product with two attributes, color y size, 
Colour has Red(+$50), Black(+$150), White ($+30)
Sizes has M(+$25), L(+15),XL(+58)

And you'll have multiple variations, in this case, 9 I think.

Now you have 10 different attributes, each with 20 or 30 possible values.

You'll have thousands of variations, this is what makes the site crash. I need to find a way to code or modify the system queries so this variation are less heavy and have fewer iterations, since if as soon as I try to load the product on the site, my database just dies.

Thank you.

Comment: It is hard for me to imagine that many attributes being practice, *but* WC2.4 is currently in beta and is should improve the performance of variations.